# Very large string arrays not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with 58112 words. However, when I try to check if a word is in the list, it always returns false, except for the first word. I'm not going to post my code because that would be too large, but here is some of the main stuff:

```js
isWord("a") //true
isWord("hello") //false??

function isWord(word) {
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (word == words[i]) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

`words[]` is the list of 58112 words. The first word is "a", of course. When I do `isWord("a")`, it returns true, like expected. If I do anything other than "a", It returns false. Why does this occur? Is it because I exceeded the maximum array limit? I don't think so.
The words I used are from **[this](https://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_lowercase.txt)** *(I had to add the "a" and the "i" because they didn't have one)*.

Comment: Move the `return false` to the outside of the loop. You are prematurely exiting the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you made it

```
return false;
```

That would make it so that anything after the return statement does not execute (and as a result your code stops executing after one iteration). I would recommend replacing it with a print statement or storing the result in a Boolean variable and printing it elsewhere, OR maybe returning the Boolean variable so you don't have to change a lot of the other code. That can be done this way:

```
isWord("a") //true
isWord("hello") //false??

function isWord(word) {
  var boolean check = false;   //setting it to false by default removes the need for the "else" statement
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (word == words[i]) {
      check = true;
    }
  }
  return check;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. I did not use it exactly, I did this: `function isWord(word) {
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  var tf = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (word == words[i]) {
      tf = true;
      
    }
  }
  return tf;
}` without your help, I wouldn't have been able to do this so...<br> and I don't get why `} else { return false; }` would interfere with my code..

Comment: as i previously mentioned anything after a return statement does not execute so if i have


 {
  return <1>;
  return <2>;
 }


the second return statement will not execute.


Your code was set up in such a way that only the first element stored in the array  `words[]` would be checked, so if the word to be checked was “a” (which was the first (technically 0th) element in array words, i.e, words[0]) it would return true, otherwise it would return false and the function would stop executing. It wouldn’t check the second element so anything that isn’t “a” would return false.

Comment: this answer actually helped me with a few other projects I've been working on.

Comment: Thats great! Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I think this is because when you are checking whether the word is in the words array or not.

In the first iteration of the array if it finds that the word that you entered is `a` which is the value of `words[0]`, it returns `true`. Otherwise, if it it returns `false` and exits out of the function.

So essentially it only checks whether the element you entered is equal to `a` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a faster and more concise way to achieve the same functionality.

```js
function isWord(word) {
    word = word.toLowerCase()
    var i = word.length;
    while (i--) {
       if (words[i] === word) {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Since ES7 (ES2016)](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_2016.asp), two appropriate methods has been added:

```js
const words = ['hi', 'bye', 'morning', 'evening'];
const toSearch = 'Morning';

if (words.includes(toSearch.toLowerCase())) {
  // ...
}
// or
if (words.some(x => x === toSearch.toLowerCase())) {
  // ...
}
```

While array's items are comparable by `===`, using `includes` method is a better choice. Keep in mind, if `===` doesn't satisfy, use `some` method to customize it.

Use case of `some` method, where `includes` doesn't work:

```js
const objects = [{ id: 1, name: 'Foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'bar' }, { id: 3, name: 'Baz' }];
const idToSearch = 2;

if (objects.some(x => x.id === idToSearch)) {
  // ...
}
```

Also, `find` and `findIndex` methods are there already, [since ES6 (ES2015)](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp#mark_array_find)